# CLLocation Class Swift

Tags: swift, maps

I've been currently experimenting with Google maps and came across a method available to CoreLocation that Apple provides.

The method being:

### func distance(from: CLLocation) Returns the distance (measured in meters) from the receiver’s location to the specified location.

Now what has peaked my interest is how this method comes to the outputted results, after converting the meters into miles. I compared the result to the distance worked out by Google maps and found it to be vastly different. My question is does the distance function work out the distance in a straight line and disregard turnings (i.e roads, motorways etc), which in essence adds to the distance calculated.

This is my implementation which uses the method mentioned above.

```
 func testDistance(lat0: Double, long0: Double, lat1: Double, long1: Double){

        let coordinate₀ = CLLocation(latitude: lat0, longitude: long0)
        let coordinate₁ = CLLocation(latitude: lat1, longitude: long1)
        let distanceInMeters = coordinate₀.distance(from: coordinate₁)
        let distanceInMile = distanceInMeters/1609.344
        print("\(distanceInMile) miles")

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

CLLocation's `distance(from: CLLocation)` function calculates using a straight line between the two locations (accounting for the curvature of the earth).

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocation/1423689-distance

> This method measures the distance between the two locations by tracing
>   a line between them that follows the curvature of the Earth. The
>   resulting arc is a smooth curve and does not take into account
>   specific altitude changes between the two locations.

Answer (score 0):

There are different, equally valid definitions of the distance between points. The location manager calculates distance "as the crow flies", or along the spherical surface of the earth. (Also known as "great circle" distance.)

Then there is driving distance. That accounts for the route you have to take, which is always longer than the "straight line" distance (which is actually on the curve Earth's surface.)

Comment: Makes sense! sorry if the question seems very basic.